# Unable to change button text after successful form send through ajax request to the server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, express

I am unable to show modified button text through ajax handlers and I am able to submit form data but can't show the success message to user in front end.

```
exports.postEntriesCollection = (req, res) => {
    Campaign.findOne({ slug:req.params.slug }, function(err, campaign) {
        const photo = new PhotoEntries({
            Email:req.body.email,
            Name:req.body.name,
            Description:req.body.description,
            Phonenumber:req.body.Phone, 
            CampaignId:campaign._id,
    });
    photo.save().then(photo => {
        req.flash('success', { msg: 'Uploaded successfully' });
        res.status(200).json({ 'status': 200, msg: 'Completed' })  
    });
 }
**Ajax request form is :**
```

form is submitted but the button text is not working?Is there any additionally required to get response from server and apply in front end? I want to implement to show success or some message to user after form submission. How can achieve that?
This is my ajax code to send form which has ID with `contactMesubmit` and submitting form but not able to show success message which is sending from backend.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contactMesubmit").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
        var data = new FormData(form);
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: "/photoapp/<%=slug%> ",
            data: data,
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                if( msg == 'Completed' ){
                    $("#contactMesubmit").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("button #contactMesubmit").html("success")
                }
                else {
                    $("#contactMesubmit").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            }      
        });  
    });  
});
```

I want when form submitted the response will send to front as msg:Completed and i am checking the msg in front end with if condition and alter the button text accordingly.?

Comment: remove space from `$("button#contactMesubmit")`

Comment: still not working

Comment: how does your button look alike ? show your html.

Comment: <button  id="contactMesubmit"  class="btn" type="submit"  >Send a free request</button>

Comment: it should work fine . are you seeing any error in browser console .

Comment: showing "Uncaught (in promise) undefined " but there it goes to entire page , error is not showing in specific place

Comment: if(msg=='Completed'){
    console.log('done');
    $("#contactMesubmit").prop("disabled", false);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226505/discussion-between-swati-and-rudra-simha).

Comment: if(msg=='Completed'){
    console.log('done');
    $("#contactMesubmit").prop("disabled", false);  when I check console.log  IT IS WROKING upto before success after conditional check it is not working